# How do I get my exe on Windows' list of associated applications?

Tags: winapi, delphi-xe5

I have a program that catalogs jpgs in a database.  It has the ability to read files off any USB-attached device.

I would like to offer the user the option to make this the deferred application for USB events, or at least to show up on the list of applications available.

Is this something I can do through Delphi?

Comment: This feature is called Hardware AutoPlay. See [How to Register a Handler for a Device Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh127452(v=vs.85).aspx) and the other items in the [Using Hardware AutoPlay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144210(v=vs.85).aspx) chapter. :)

Comment: Also check out [Supporting AutoPlay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375751(v=vs.85).aspx) which is in the same book as the links, above.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks!  I'll start digging :D